# Default docker registry in Docker desktop

Tags: docker, kubernetes-helm, docker-registry, skaffold

I'm building docker images via jib and skaffold. When I provide the image key `service-1` in skaffold build.artifacts.image, an image is created (Image named 'service-1:SHA256') and I can see that through `docker image ls`. Then in skaffold deploy, I provide kubectl commands, where its picking up the image created just fine. In my deployment.yaml manifest file, I specify just spec.template.spec.containers.image : service-1

The above method is working fine, but I want to do helm. I have created helm charts. But helm is not able to pickup any image from my local docker daemon repo. If I specify image:service-1:SHA256 that's present when I see `docker image ls`, I get ErrImagePull.

Why isn't helm able to pick the image from my local docker registry. I'm also not able to docker pull service-1:sha256.

What's the default docker registry that's being used, and how is skaffold with kubectl able to pull the image correctly, while helm and docker cannot.

I tried skaffold+helm also, but faced the same issue.

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: service-1
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: service-1
      jib:
        project: com.sample.app:service-1
        args:
          - -Dmaven.test.skip
deploy:
  helm:
    releases:
      - name: service-1
        chartPath: service-1-chart
        values:
          image: service-1
        valuesFiles:
          - service-1-chart/values.yaml
```

Getting the following during pod describe

```
  Normal   Scheduled  75s                default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/service1-df75c747b-g6qfm to docker-desktop
  Normal   Pulling    29s (x3 over 74s)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Pulling image "service-1:e7d693388f7f26a062257408e3cfb5904da4749342729802eb9ac65fab6d2f31"
  Warning  Failed     27s (x3 over 73s)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Failed to pull image "service-1:e7d693388f7f26a062257408e3cfb5904da4749342729802eb9ac65fab6d2f31": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for service-1, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
  Warning  Failed     27s (x3 over 73s)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    2s (x4 over 72s)   kubelet, docker-desktop  Back-off pulling image "service-1:e7d693388f7f26a062257408e3cfb5904da4749342729802eb9ac65fab6d2f31"
  Warning  Failed     2s (x4 over 72s)   kubelet, docker-desktop  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

When I try to do docker pull:

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for service-1, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Comment: Should I setup my local docker so that it uses artifactory as the remote registry? I always thought docker was able to store all images locally for local development. Doesn't make sense for me to upload images during each skaffold build stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use Docker registry, but to run the image directly from your Docker Daemon, then add `imagePullPolicy: Never`.

Comment: Yes, looks like this worked. I had explicitly set ImagePullPolicy to always in Helm Values.yaml